# Validate XML Integrity in Mule

Tags: xml, mule

Occasionally an XML file is not transferred properly, and we end up with incomplete XML.

Ex.

```
<ORDER_STATUS>
<SALES_ORDER_STATUS>
    <ORDER_HEADER>
    </ORDER_HEADER>
</SALES_ORD
```

What would your suggestion be to catch these occurrences in a Mule flow?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to validate the XML is valid you could just use a DataWeave expression to try to transform it:

```
<set-variable variableName="test" value="#[output application/java --- payload]" />
```

To read the XML DataWeave needs to validate it. You can enclose the set variable in a Try scope to handle the possible error if it is invalid.

In case that you have an XSD schema, or can write on, you could use the [XML Module  validation operation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/1.2/xml-schema-validation).